# Wt 3 memory deallocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, wt

Mostly it's clear where memory is deallocated in wt 3(very explicit in wt 4) but in this case I don't understand the logic.

The below function content sets a container for my wt 3 application. Everything works fine but could anyone explain how is (or should this) returned _content be handled?

_content is kept as private class data.

```
Wt::WContainerWidget* _content;
```

Function content() handles container

```
Wt::WContainerWidget* web::content() 
{
    if (_content == 0) {
       _content = new Wt::WContainerWidget(root()); //memory allocation
    }
    return _content; //allocated memory gets returned
}
```

later this is used like:

```
void web::sayhi()
{
    content()->addWidget(new Wt::WBreak());
    content()->addWidget(new Wt::WText("hello world"));
}
```

How is this suppose to delete/handle allocated memory returned by content()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this form of the constructor:

```
_content = new Wt::WContainerWidget(root());
```

Then the widget is added to `root()` as a child, so it's owned by `root()`. `_content` is actually non-owning in this case.

So, when the `WApplication` is destroyed, the `root()` and every child of `root()` is destroyed with it.

This is equivalent to doing this in Wt 4:

```
_content = root()->addWidget(std::make_unique<Wt::WContainerWidget>());
```

or shorter (since Wt 4.0.1):

```
_content = root()->addNew<Wt::WContainerWidget>();
```

Comment: I thought some kind of wizardry like that is going on, many thanks. I don't really understand how root() can take ownership like that though :(

Comment: In the constructor of `WWebWidget` and `WCompositeWidget`, `parent->addWidget(this)` is called.

This takes careful programming, though, because at that point, `this` is still a `WWebWidget` or `WCompositeWidget` instead of a specific widget, so `addWidget` should not rely on any special properties of the concrete widget.

Because of the issues that arise from this, and because it's incompatible with the use of `unique_ptr`, this is no longer possible in Wt 4.

Answer (score 0):

You should store content as a variable member stored by value, instead of a pointer. If you must keep content as a pointer then you may want to explore the use of smart pointers (std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr)

Comment: That would be great of course but it seems it doesn't work so.
Given error is as follows:
could not convert ‘((web*)this)->web::_content’ from ‘Wt::WContainerWidget*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<Wt::WContainerWidget>’